# How do I get my dictionary to begin a new line when writing code to a file from a program?

Tags: python, dictionary, format

Here is my code sample, and below is an example of what I'm trying to do. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
cards = {}
import sys



n = 0

while True:
   n += .01
   cards[n] = {'name': str(input('Please enter name: ')),
            'year': int(input('Please enter a year: ')),
            'brand': str(input('Please enter a brand: ')),
            'make': str(input('Please enter a make: ')),
            'parallel': (input('parallel - Y OR N? ')),
            'auto': (input('auto - Y OR N? ')),
            'rookie_card': (input('rookie card - Y OR N? ')),
            'numbered': (input('numbered - Y OR N? ')),
            'card_num': input('Please enter a card number: '),
            }
           

      
            
            # 'parallel_type': 
                
            # 'serial_num':


print(cards)

   while True:
       choice = input('Press Y to continue or N to exit: ').capitalize()
       if choice == 'Y':
           break
       elif choice == 'N':
           print('Next input n = ', n)
        
           try:
               cards_file = open('cards_file.py', 'wt')
               cards_file.write(str(cards))
               cards_file.close()
    
           except:
               print('Unable to write to file')               


           sys.exit()
       else:
           print('Please enter a valid option!')
```

This is what I am working with. Everytime my program writes onto the cards_file.py I want the dictionary to start a new line like so:

```
cards = {1: {'name':'some_name', 'year': 'some_year', 'brand': 'brand'},
------->{2: { -------------------new line of data---------------------}
        }
```

Comment: you have to write own function for this - it will have to use `for`-loop to write every element from dictionary separatelly and add `'\n` at the end. You can't do this with simple `cards_file.write(str(cards))`

Comment: thank you this helped very much

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
cards_file.write(str(cards))
```

With

```
for k,v in cards.items():
    cards_file.write(f'{k} : {v}\n')
```

Comment: can't seem to get that to work as directed. I'm a beginner if that wasn't already obvious by my code.

Comment: I think you forgot `\n` in `write()`